# Accidentally marked a USB hard-disk as "Active": consequences?

Tags: windows-server-2008, boot, partition, hard-drive

In the "Disk management" section of the "Computer management" console I accidentally hit the context menu option "*Mark as Active Partition*" for an external USB hard-disk, that was connected on a Windows 2008 x64 server.

Now the disk appears as "Active" in the disk list. I can't find a way to undo this change, and I'm not sure what are the consequences of this mistake... Can I just remove my USB HD and get away with it? Will the server be still able to boot regularly? Is there something I should do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody cares, I finally asked my senior sysadm, he said my mistake didn't affect the server's partitions, it only added the *Active* flag to the USB hard-disk's partition. No big deal then.